# Split String with 1 known and some unknown characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I am wanting / needing to split a string by a specific character, for instance a '/' that I can reliably expect, but I need to know what the characters directly in front of that character are up to the space before those characters.

For example:

let myStr = `"bob u/ used cars nr/ no resale value i/ information is attached to the vehicle tag bb/ Joe's wrecker service"`

So, I can split by the '/' already using

`mySplitStr = myStr.split('/');`

But now mySplitStr is an array like

`mySplitStr[1] = "bob u"
mySplitStr[2] = " used cars nr"
mySplitStr[3] = " no resale value i"`
etc

I need, however, to know what the characters are just prior to the '/'.

`u
nr
i`
etc

so that I know what to do with the information following the '/'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm maybe find the index at "/" then use charAt(index of "/" minus 1). Is that what you are looking for? a way to find the character before "/" right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this regular expression argument for the `split`:

```
let parts = myStr.split(/\s*(\S+)\/\s*/);
```

Now you will have the special characters at every odd position in the resulting array.

```js
let myStr = "bob u/ used cars nr/ no resale value i/ information is attached to the vehicle tag bb/ Joe's wrecker service";
let parts = myStr.split(/\s*(\S+)\/\s*/);

console.log(parts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For a more structured result, you could use these special character combinations as keys of an object:

```js
let myStr = "bob u/ used cars nr/ no resale value i/ information is attached to the vehicle tag bb/ Joe's wrecker service";
let obj = myStr.split(/\s*(\S+)\/\s*/).reduceRight( (acc, v) => {
    if (acc.default === undefined) {
        acc.default = v;
    } else {
        acc[v] = acc.default;
        acc.default = undefined;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: The question asks to produce the list `'u', 'nr', 'i' etc`, not `  "bob", "u", "used cars" ...`. This is exactly why I personally stay away from regex -- they are hard

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko, ...and OP continues to say *"so that I know what to do with the information following the '/'. "*. So the context is needed. This difference in interpretation of the question has nothing to do with regex.

Comment: I see that line, but the requirement is then unclear at best. The input is provided, but the precise output is not. At least, you and me are interpreting it differently.

Comment: Well I will not downvote your answer for it though ;-)

Comment: I think, you should, as long you believe that my answer is incorrect. Voting is about correctness, not politeness, am I wrong?

Comment: I don't believe either answer is incorrect. The difference in interpretation is really a detail that is not essential. In both cases the OP will get enough for resolving their issue. I have in the mean time added a more handy output structure.

Comment: So, now it's a combination of a regex **and** transformation function...

Comment: To make it an object with key/value correspondances, yes. I think this is helpful for the OP, but you are free to answer as you see fit. No problem.;-)

Comment: 1. I appreciate the discussion around this. 2 I apologize for not being more clear with my desire in my question, but honestly, I was just posting the question based on what I thought could be done, so 3. Thank you for taking it a step further with the second possible way to do this.  Amazing answer.

Comment: @another-guy, maybe you can now remove your downvote?

Comment: @trincot done, but now I feel stupid for not being given a chance for a correct answer due to a "funny" problem definition. Still, I believe using a regex should be a last resort always (who's gonna maintain the solution?!) Mandatory kxcd: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/perl_problems.png

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you're looking for:

```
"bob u/ used cars nr/ no resale value i/ information is attached to the vehicle tag bb/ Joe's wrecker service"
  .split('/')
  .map(splitPart => {
    const wordsInPart = splitPart.split(' ');
    return wordsInPart[wordsInPart.length - 1];
  });

// Produces: ["u", "nr", "i", "bb", "service"]
```

Splitting by `'/'` is not enough. You also need to visit every part of your split result and extract the last "work" from it.

Answer (score 0):

After you split your string, you indeed get an array, where the last set of characters is the one you want to know, and you can grab it with this:

```
let mySplitStr = myStr.split('/');
for(let i = 0; i < mySplitStr.length; i++) {
    let mySplitStrEl = mySplitStr[i].split(" "); // Split current text element
    let lastCharsSet = mySplitStrEl[mySplitStrEl.length -1]; // Grab its last set of characters
    let myCurrentStr = mySplitStrEl.splice(mySplitStrEl.length -1, 1); // Remove last set of characters from text element
        myCurrentStr = mySplitStrEl.join(" "); // Join text element back into a string
    switch(lastCharsSet) {
        case "u":
            // Your code here
        case "nr":
            // Your code here
        case "i":
            // Your code here
    }
}
```

Inside the loop, for the first iteration:

```
// lastCharsSet is "u"
// myCurrentStr is "bob"
```